# Convert time to HH-MM-SS TSQL - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, sql-server-2012, format

I have quite a lot of rows returned using the query below, I have the date formatted how I like it, I just need the same doing with the time. It currently shows as: 500 for 0500 or 220000 for 2200 how can I make it so the time displays as HH-MM-SS in the query below:

```
SELECT Jobname AS OptimiseJobs,
CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), RunDate), 112),105) AS Date,

FROM Tablename
WHERE jobname LIKE '%Optimise'
```

Thanks again all, I will get the hand of this eventually

Comment: Do you want date and time in one column or in two different columns?

Comment: Two different columns

Answer (score 0):

try `CONVERT(varchar(8), RunDate, 114) AS Time`

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17469)**

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'hh-mm-ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test
(
timeofday time(0)
)

insert test
(timeofday)
values
('16:30')
select * from test
-- 16:30:00

select cast(timeofday as datetime) from test
-- 1900-01-01 16:30:00.000

select format(timeofday,'HH:mm') from test
--NULL

select format( cast(timeofday as datetime),'HH:mm') from test
-- 16:30

select format( cast(timeofday as datetime),'h:mm tt') from test
--  4:30 PM
```